# Disable password and enable SSH keygen like AWS EC2 instances

Tags: authentication, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I have a Proxmox hypervisor with 6 LXCs (servers) I have SFTP with chrooted user enabled on 4 of 6 LXCs with a custom port per LXC. Now I want the key authentication in FileZilla exactly like Amazon Web Services EC2 instances (a `key.pem` compatible with FileZilla and a authorized_keys file on my server in `/home/user/.ssh/`)

How to generate a key to .pem format who contents ? :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I know it's a noob question but I think it's first time I don't find what I want on Google or here on Stack Overflow

Thanks,

(Sorry for my English I'm a French baguette)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to generate a key to .pem format who contents ? :

Using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f rsa.pem`. Without any arguments, you will get the default location and configuration.

Other possibility is to use OpenSSL, that should do the same:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
```

Comment: Nope, I get only id_rsa and id_rsa.pub, I want .pem file 100% compatible with FileZilla and authorized_key file

Comment: it is just different name. `id_rsa` is your PEM file and `id_rsa.pub` is the part you are pasting in the `authorized_keys` file. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I've already tried to rename id_rsa to serverkey.pem but when I add it in FileZilla it's not compatible and requests a conversion to .ppk file while AWS EC2 .pem keys are 100% compatible, why ?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. The default probably changed and it looks like I still have the old keys format. I added details how to convert RFC format to PEM.

Comment: Oh okay I understand now ! But rsa.pem genered by `ssh-keygen -e -m pem -f id_rsa > rsa.pem` isn't valid when I add it on FileZilla because nothing happens

Comment: Oh ... it is public key. So other possibility is to use OpenSSL directly as I added do the answer.

Comment: That's okay now I used :

`openssl genrsa -out $HOSTNAME.pem 2048` + `chmod $HOSTNAME.pem` + `ssh-keygen -y -f $HOSTNAME.pem > authorized_keys`

Thanks you very much :D